# How to differentiate an app is back from background with back from another activity within the app

Tags: android

Is there any way to tell whether an app is back from background(click home button to be background) or back from another activity within the app?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789300/4049612](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789300/4049612)

Comment: @Jacky  what is your exact issue mention your code here other wise there is no way to resolve your issue what you implement in your code and what you exactly wants to do

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` callback you can get `Intent`. This `Intent` should an extra where have the information about previous Activity.

Here is example:

Suppose `ActivityB` is loaded from `ActivityA` and `ActivityC`. From `activityA` you can load `ActivityB` via this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "ActivityA");
startActivity(intent);
```

and if want from `ActivityC` you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "ActivityC");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your ActivityB `onCreate` method you just use this line:

```
String fromActivity = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("FROM_ACTIVITY");
```

Here, `fromActivity` Strings contains previous activity information.

That's it :)